# What is a 'for' loop initial declaration and why can I not use it?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

```
void display()
{
    if(front==-1)
    {
        printf("\n QUEUE IS UNDERFLOW");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=front;i<=rear;i++)
        {
            printf("\n %d",queue[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

An error occured in array implementation of queue in C program

Area of error : void display()

**ERROR:
[Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode**

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @jaswanth Switch on the option for C99 or C11 or use a more modern compiler.

Comment: You get the error because you use an old version of the C standard. What compiler are you using? How are you building your application?

Comment: it show's me an error like this **[Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode**

Comment: On an unrelated note, please make it a habit to use *trailing* newline in your output. When your program runs from a terminal a leading newline will print the *previous* line. A trailing newline will print the current line.

Comment: What is your platform compiler/IDE/developement environnement?

Answer (score 3):

You're using an outdated C compiler (maybe Turbo C?) which does not allow 'for' loop initial declarations:

Change this:

```
for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++)
```

to this:

```
int i;
for (i = front; i <= rear; i++)
```

Or (better) get a more modern C compiler.

Comment: thanks it's working now .